# WPF button enable/disable problem

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm somewhat new to WPF and VB.Net (but not new to programming in general) and I was wondering if someone could help me with an issue that I'm having.

Here's the problem:

I am creating a simple form using WPF in VB.Net and I have a button that I want to disable or enable based on an update to a DataGrid that is located in the form. When I first show the form the button is enabled by default and everything is fine. When the DataGrid changes I can disable the button programmatically by doing `btnTest.IsEnabled=False` and the button grays out appropriately. However, when I subsequently call `btnTest.IsEnabled=True` the button becomes enabled all except for the text that is displayed on the button; that text remains grayed out. I can switch back and forth between enabled and disabled several times and the behavior described still manifests. I'm not sure if I'm missing something but this seems to be a really simple problem to me and I've wasted a few hours on it already.

Does anyone know what's going on? I've already googled everything I know.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: could you show the code you are using and some of hte xaml that defines the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update this: I actually found out that this was a bug in the BureauBlue theme that ships with .NET. If you have this problem tag me in a comment here and I can send you my modified BureauBlue.xaml file.

Comment: Hi Tom, I'd be interested in seeing your BureauBlue.xaml file, as I have the same problem. Chris

Comment: @ChrisSpicer I posted it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/P4QyWaZN It's been a while since I modified it so I don't really remember any details but you should be able to do a file diff and see the modifications. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Yep, that fixed the problem. Looking at the diff, it was the addition of some Exit Actions to clear the storyboard formatting. Thanks very much for posting your xaml.